# Nodejs Mysql: Query-Escaping adds single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, escaping

I'm trying to escape my SQL Create Table Query. It adds single quotes to query which results in an error.

```
    let table = "SomeTable";
    let query_table = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (ID_Charge int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ID_Machine int, FOREIGN KEY (ID_Maschine) REFERENCES Machine (ID_Machine))";

    con.query(query_table, `${table}_Users` (err) => {
    (...)
```

Error I'm getting is this:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''SomeTable_Users' (ID_Charge int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   ID_Maschine int' at line 1",

Why am I getting an error if the Table name is kept in single quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that it's being escaped as a "value" rather than as an "identifier". Depending on which package you are using to do the query, you can mark that it should be escaped as an identifier. If you're using the `mysql` package, you can do:

```
let table = "SomeTable";
let query_table = 
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?? (ID_Charge int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ID_Machine int, FOREIGN KEY (ID_Maschine) REFERENCES Machine (ID_Machine))";

con.query(query_table, [`${table}_Users`], (err) => {
(...)
```

Note the double `??` means "this is an identifier, not a value".

If you use [@databases/mysql](https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/mysql) as the driver you can do:

```
con.query(sql`
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${sql.ident(`${table}_Users`)}
  (
    ID_Charge int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Machine int,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Maschine) REFERENCES Machine (ID_Machine)
  )`
);
```

See https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/sql#sqlidentnames

N.B. depending on how your library is consumed, you may also want to whitelist the allowed table names with something like:

```
if (!['table1', 'table2'].includes(table)) throw new Error('Invalid table name');
```

You may also need to use

```
`${table}_Users`.toLowerCase();
```

Depending on how the case sensitivity is configured in your database.